# Parse JSON with Power Query in Excel in the same way FetchJson does in Google sheets

Tags: excel, powerquery, urlfetch

I want to pare JSONs in Excel using Power Query that have the following structure

[image]

Here the link:
https://sum-app.net/projects/15222520210510875/download_data/kumu_json

I can do this in Google sheets with `FetchJson` with the following but I have had no luck using Ecexls Power query doing the same

How to do this with Power Query in Excel?

Thanks in advance for your assistance with this

//get JSON Data for elements
var data=FetchJSON(jsonlink ,"|", "elements");

//get Json Data for Connections
var data=FetchJSON(jsonlink ,"|", "connections");

```
 //get Json Data for element
function FetchJSON(jsonlink ,separator, what) {

// Set Fetch Variables
  var response     = UrlFetchApp.fetch(jsonlink);
  var responseText = response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText);

  if(what=="elements"){
  let myDico = new Map();
  responseJson.elements.forEach(function(key){
    Object.keys(key).forEach(function(item){
       myDico.set(item,'')
    })
  })
  var elementKeys = []
  myDico.forEach(function(value, key) {
    elementKeys.push(key)
  });
  var data = responseJson.elements.map(e => elementKeys.map(f => {
      return e[f] instanceof Array ? e[f].join(separator) : e[f];
  })); 
  data.unshift(elementKeys);
  
  } 
  else if(what=="connections"){
   let myDico2 = new Map()
   responseJson.connections.forEach(function(key){
    Object.keys(key).forEach(function(item){
       myDico2.set(item,'')
    })
  })
  var connectionKeys = []
  myDico2.forEach(function(value, key) {
    connectionKeys.push(key)
  })
  var data = responseJson.connections.map(e => connectionKeys.map(f => {
      return e[f] instanceof Array ? e[f].join(separator) : e[f];
  })); 
  data.unshift(connectionKeys);

  };
  //data = data.map(x => x.map(y => typeof y === 'undefined' || null ? "" : y));

  return data
}
```

Edit: Here is what the output needs to look like
(Column order in not important)
Element data
[image]

Connection data
[image]

Google sheet with data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yO3gX61MroPrYL2l1YnfDxloa5naAX6HG2Q2f5ED_lY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you want for output

Comment: Added. Sorry about overlooking that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
let  Source =Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\kumu_json.json")),
Expanded=Table.FromRecords (Source[elements] ),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Expanded, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Combine items in list" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", each try if Value.Is(_, type list ) then Text.Combine(_,", ") else _ otherwise _, type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Combine items in list", List.Distinct(#"Combine items in list"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),each {_,type text}))
in  #"Changed Type"
```

Comment: I spoke too you soon. Works great, but the first column the `Id` column is missing its data

Comment: hmm, all `number` field are `not` being outputted to table but show in the query builder

Comment: OK, updated code to add row to convert format  Very odd